# spring cloud dataflow multiple instances of processor in one stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm new to spring cloud dataflow. I'm wondering if it is possible to have multiple instances of a processor in one stream.

For example

```
source | processor | sink
```

Can I configure it so that there are 2 instances of the `processor` app both subscribe the `source` in a round robin fashion and pipe the output to `sink`?

I know it is possible with 2 streams and named destination, but I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve this with 1 stream definition but perhaps with some properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the general idea. Use the deployer property `count` for the processor app. Look on the data flow dashboard, deploy screen, under generic deployer properties.

[image]